# How to set the global array values inside another function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, multidimensional-array

I am using ajax call to retrieve the values from database and then trying to insert those values into arrays(declared globally).But Outside the called function if I am trying to check the value of arrays it is showing empty arrays. Here is the my code:

```js
function functionName() {

  var arr1 = [];
  var arr2 = [];

  $(function() {

    $.ajax({
      url: "RandomURL",
      data: {
        some random data
      }
    }).done(
      function(data) {
        console.log(data.data);

        for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
          arr1.push({
            x: data.data[i][0],
            y: data.data[i][1]
          });
          arr2.push({
            x: data.data[i][0],
            y: data.data[i][2]
          });
        }

      });

  });
  console.log(arr1);
  console.log(arr2);

  return [{
    values: arr1,
    key: 'array1 values',
    color: '#ff7f0e'
  }, {
    values: arr2,
    key: 'arr2 values',
    color: '2ca02c'
  }];

}
```

Comment: Try moving `console.log` in the ajax callback.

Comment: ajax is asynchronous. you cant return values from ajax like that

Comment: what have you done here? you have written $(function()) inside functionName() ??

Comment: Can you please tell how to return the array value? I have to pass the array to another function for plotting the graph using nvd3 library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change as below, you do not need to return these array to another function as you have declared it as global below:

```
    var arr1 = [];
    var arr2 = [];

    function functionName() { 

    $.ajax({
          url: "RandomURL",
          data: {
            some random data
          }
        }).done(
          function(data) {
            console.log(data.data);

            for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
              arr1.push({
                x: data.data[i][0],
                y: data.data[i][1]
              });
              arr2.push({
                x: data.data[i][0],
                y: data.data[i][2]
              });
            }

          });

      console.log(arr1);
      console.log(arr2);


    }
```

So you can assign values in plod data like:

```
var plotData = [{
    values: arr1,
    key: 'array1 values',
    color: '#ff7f0e'
  }, {
    values: arr2,
    key: 'arr2 values',
    color: '2ca02c'
  }];
```

Comment: The flow for plotting the graph is like this:

nv.addGraph(function() {

....

 var plotData = functionName();

....

}

function functionName() { 
.....
return ...
}

Comment: I have updated the code above for passing values in plotData

Comment: Depending on how soon all of the other functionality is set up, whether the arrays are set on the root level or not, there is a chance for the data to not be populated in time. You might want to test it with a slow connection to the database to make sure that is ruled out. But it's good to hear that it looks better with this change.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning information and using console logs outside of the AJAX success. AJAX is asynchronous by default in JQuery. You could set it to async: false in the settings but it usually is recommended to be asynchronous.

If you want to keep it asynchronous you would need to really do all of the work in the done/success part of the ajax. This brings up potential issues due to needing possible more global variables that aren't encapsulated and call further functions with subsequent work within them.

Or it could then bring you down the path of promises so that functions are called in subsequent order as ajax calls are completed.

```
function callAjax() {
  $.ajax(...

  ...done(function(data) {
    // do work and then
    plotUsingData();
  });
}

function plotUsingData() {
 // now the graph or display of data is created after the content is loaded
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`var arr1 = [];` doesn't really create global variable. `arr1 = [];` does.